# What does this mean? Friend gave this on a piece of paper, and wanted me to translate this: こんな憂鬱なバレンタインは初めてやワクワクイべントのはずなのに!

Tags: translation

(I was unsure of the fourth and fifth character).

I'm fairly certain that I read it correctly, except for the fifth character. The fifth character in the text looked very similar to that but it looked like there was a bottom (almost-) horizontal stroke going from left to right, but I couldn't find a character more similar to it.

I think it means something like: Valentine's day is always depressing, but this one should be the most exciting day

or the opposite:
It's the first Valentine's day that is depressing, and it's supposed to be an exciting day

Comment: The fourth and fifth characters should be 憂鬱.

Comment: Is it nonsensical with the original characters? (and edited, thanks!)

Answer (score 3):

> こんな憂鬱なバレンタインは初めてやワクワクイべントのはずなのに!

your translation : "*Valentine's day is **always** depressing, but this one should be the most exciting day.* ".

I think it's almost there, however, I am not sure about from where "*always*" comes. It contradicts to 「初めてや」: "for the first time". So, you don't need it and add "for the first time" into your sentence (Probably I will add "this" in the beginning of the sentence).

Your 2nd translation : "*It's the first Valentine's day that is depressing, and it's supposed to be an exciting day.*" is almost perfect to me. Probably you can add "so" or some emphasis before depressing.

---

For the kanji part, it was also challenging for me remembering how to read and write「鬱{うつ}」for the first time. From my personal experience, I broke them down into the familiar components into「木」,「缶」,「木」,「凶」and「ウヒャー」since its strokes were so intricate for me. Then, I tried to connote them as yucky things and practiced how to write them over and over again.

I remember the member from "L'Arc-en-ciel", one of the most famous J-Rock band, had needed to remember how to write their song title :[『夏{なつ}の憂鬱{ゆううつ}』](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iIDwidnRp-Y). You can read kanji, but you can't write it sometimes, so don't worry about that too much.

Comment: Thank you!  
So I think the final translation is "It's the first Valentine's day that is so depressing, and it's supposed to be an exciting day."  
  
I'm still confused on the meaning. Does it imply that other Valentine's days have been exciting while this coming one isn't?

Comment: @user36838 I think so. It is natural to think of the author usually has been enjoying the Valentine's day other than this year. They have experienced the event multiple times guessing from 「初めてや」and was expecting this day as exciting event guessing from「ワクワクイべントのはずなのに!」.